# Facebook Chat v5 design overlay issue

Tags: css, facebook, chat

Facebook chat is awesome, plug and play.
However, it looks and positions itself pretty badly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/akFLu.jpg

I`m looking for a way to style it so its out of the way.
As it is, it covers the agreement for cookies, and buy buttons on product pages, which is unnaceptable.

The end goal is to have something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyJra.jpg

A small button which would expand the chat and I can place either in he left or right lower side.

Is something like this possible with Facebook chat?

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v5.0'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-customerchat"
attribution=setup_tool
page_id="##########"
theme_color="#E34F4B"
logged_in_greeting="Здравейте, с какво може да бъдем полезни?"
logged_out_greeting="Здравейте, с какво може да бъдем полезни?">
</div>
```

Comment: Generally you'll get more helpful answers if you post the CSS that you've tried already along with a minimal viable test case so people can edit your CSS and show you how they would solve it.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Thats just the thing. I have working CSS changes to show. Recently I switched to v5, and it comes with this huge label for the chat on mobile.
For the previous version it was just a small circle which I had positioned with a bit of margin.

Comment: _“A small button which would expand the chat”_ - isn’t that what this plugin already offers? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin

Comment: @04FS It comes preexpanded on mobile, where the issue is.
Desktop isnt the problem.
Also, on mobile, its centered, not tiny and to the side, its on the screenshots.

Comment: Please show us how you actually configured and embedded the plugin, instead of just showing screenshots.

Comment: @04FS I`ve added the code snippet.

Comment: Sounds like you should maybe suppress the automatic showing of the greeting dialog, using the `greeting_dialog_display` option? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin#customization currently says, the default was `show` for both desktop and mobile, whereas https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/web-plugins/#attributes says, `hide` was the default on mobile. Sounds like the former might actually be correct.

Comment: @04FS Looks like it worked, using greeting_dialog_display="hide"
I added a bit of margin again o force the elemnts up and it now no longer covers the important buttons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parameter: greeting_dialog_display has to be set to 'hide'
greeting_dialog_display='hide'

Contradictions in the FB documentation:

Default to show for both web and mobile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin#customization

Default to show on web and hide on mobile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/web-plugins/#attributes